# How to pivot a table in oracle SQL that has no feature to use as columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that looks like this

```
select
    parentid,
    id
from
    table
order by
    parentid;
```

The parentid is a reference to another type of object in a different table. The records in this table are additional information about the record in the parent table, and there can be anywhere from 1 to 10 ids associated with a parent id. The records don't have any particular order, either. So right now, the query above returns something like this:

```
parentid     |     id
---------------------------
    1              10
    1              20
    1              30
    1              40
    2              50
    2              60
    3              70
    4              80
    4              90 
    4             100
```

I'd like to transform the results into a table like this

```
parentid     |     id1     |     id2     |     id3     |     id4    ....
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1               10            20            30            40
   2               50            60
   3               70
   4               80            90            100
```

I don't really care what column the ids end up in, since there's no order, but I do want each of them to be assigned to some column associated with the parent id. I thought about using pivot, but the examples I have seen make it look like you have to have an ordering or some other unique identifier associated with the ids to transform them into columns. There's no such field that could order or otherwise distinguish these records from one another. Is there a way to pivot without this, or to randomly assign some attribute that I could then use to pivot on?

Also, not sure if it will matter to the answer, but the table above is also a trivialization of the actual data for the sake of clarity - in reality there's tens of thousands of parent ids and records in this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create your column:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd6cc/11)**

```
SELECT 'ID' || ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY "parentid" ORDER BY "id") AS rn,
       "parentid", 
       "id"
FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|  RN | parentid |  id |
|-----|----------|-----|
| ID1 |        1 |  10 |
| ID2 |        1 |  20 |
| ID3 |        1 |  30 |
| ID4 |        1 |  40 |
| ID1 |        2 |  50 |
| ID2 |        2 |  60 |
| ID1 |        3 |  70 |
| ID1 |        4 |  80 |
| ID2 |        4 |  90 |
| ID3 |        4 | 100 |
```

Or use this version if have  more than 9 columns

```
SELECT 'ID' || LPAD(rn, 2, '0') as rn,
       "parentid", 
       "id"
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY "parentid" ORDER BY "id") AS rn,
           "parentid", 
           "id"
    FROM Table1
  ) T
```